# Use xcopy to backup complete folder even only one file is new

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I am trying to use `XCopy` to backup files from an old machine to a server folder. So I set up a batch file which copies each day the new files from the machine to the backup server using the following code, *(just a part of the whole code)*:

```
set /p LastSuccessfulBackup=< C:/backup/LastSuccessfulBackup.txt
set datestr=%date:~-4,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~-10,2%
xcopy "\\machine\srcfolder" "\\server\destfold\"!datestr! /s /y /i /c /d:!LastSuccessfulBackup!
```

So the idea is to check whether there are changed files in the srcfolder using `/d` and copy them to a newly generated timestamp-folder if there are changed files. It's kind of an incremental backup.

My problem is now, that I would like to have the whole folder copied and not only the changed files. Otherwise I get day by day just a backup of some few files but never the whole src-folder content.

That means that I need kind of a check, whether there are changed files and if so, copy the whole srcfolder to the backup-destination timestamp-folder.

Comment: This looks like a perfect example for using `forfiles`, the `/D` switch might be what you need. Good luck.

Comment: ... and what about `xcopy /D`? There you also have the opportunity to add a last modification date.

Comment: XCopy has a pretend mode `/l`. It will show what would be copied telling you that you have a changed file.

Comment: I already use xcopy /D as you can see in the above code. This works fine, but it copies only the files that have changed. I actually want to have a check, whether files have changed. And if there are some files which have changed, i wanna copy the hole folder (including the non-changed files) in order to have a full backup of the folder.

Comment: So you're wanting to effectively have multiple directories, each containing the entire source directory, when there has been any change, as opposed to just copying the changed files to one holding directory! I really think that you need to take a fresh look at your approach, first of all, forgetting about using `XCopy`, _which is only kept around for legacy purposes_, and use `RoboCopy` which superseded `XCopy` as far back as `Windows Vista` and has many useful options for backups. Type `RoboCopy /?` at the Command Prompt, for its usage information.

Comment: Have you thought of using FC?  You could use it to compare the two dirs, then copy the whole thing on mismatch.  Also.. Compo is on to something.. robocopy is badass.

Comment: Okay, I think I will change the approach and just use the `xcopy /d` command. So I won't have multiple directories but that's also fine for me. I will have one folder which gets updated when there are newer files. Thanks for your help!